# Can't login after upgrade to Ubuntu Budgie 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, login, do-release-upgrade, ubuntu-budgie

When I get to the login screen it doesn't recognize my password which has been unchanged for years. I tried multiple answers I found on the internet, but nothing helped. For example I tried

Drop to shell root / passwd

```
rm .Xauthority and reboot
```

Changing the following to only `quiet`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Computer specs:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro / Ubuntu Budgie 20.04
- CPU: Core i7-9750H Hexa-core 2.60 GHz
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 with 8 GB dedicated memory
- Display: 17.3" full HD (1920 x 1080) 16:9 IPS
- RAM: 32 GB, DDR4
- SSD: 512 GB

Answer (score 0):

It seem to had similar issue on new installation, but I realized username was working fine, I tried installing kde, and worked around problem. AMD Ryzen-5 MSI ASUS AM320 + MSI GTX 1650 Super Gammming + Maxtor SSD 240Gb + DATA WDC2Tb.

Comment: Hello, did you solve this issue?